# MyFrame is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerfomed (ActionEvent) Action Listener, new level

Tags: java, awt, jframe

**Самостоятельно изучаю java с помощью книжки. Такая проблема и до этого выскакивала, я просто сменил версию, не помогло.
Я нашел выход используя лямбда выражения, однако здесь они работать не будут. Буду рад вашей помощи, спасибо.**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
 class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseListener
{
private JLabel L;
private JTextField T;
private String apply="Применить ";
private String exit="Закрыть ";
public void ationPerfomed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String txt=e.getActionCommand();
    if(txt.equals(apply))
    {
        L.setText(T.getText());
    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{
    L.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    L.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
MyFrame()
{
    super("Окно с текстовым полем ");
    int w=300,h=160;
    setBounds(250,250,w,h);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    L=new JLabel();
    L.setBounds(10,10,w-25,30);
    L.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    L.addMouseListener(this);
    T= new JTextField();
    T.setBounds(L.getX(),50,L.getWidth(),30);
    int bw=(T.getWidth()-20)/2;
    JButton appB=new JButton(apply);
    appB.setBounds(T.getX(),90, bw,30);
    appB.setFocusPainted(false);
    appB.addActionListener(this);
    JButton extB= new JButton(exit);
    extB.setBounds(appB.getX()+appB.getWidth()+20,appB.getY(),appB.getWidth(),appB.getHeight());
    extB.setFocusPainted(false);
    extB.addActionListener(this);
    add(L);
    add(T);
    add(appB);
    add(extB);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
class OBRABOTCHIK2{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Пишет что ошибка в данной строчке

```
 class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseListener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе, не являющимся абстрактным, должны быть реализованы все методы интерфейсов, которые он берется реализовать. В данном случае вы не реализовали методы `mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)`(интерфейса `MouseListener`) и `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`(интерфейса `ActionListener`)(У вас опечатка - вы написали ationPerfomed)

Comment: то есть, мне нужно просто добавить такую строчку кода? ```public void mouseEntred(MouseEvent e){}```

Comment: @headhunter225014 да, и исправить опечатку.

Comment: также на англ стаке я видел, что можно добавить ```@Override```, но как и куда я не разобрался.

Comment: @headhunter225014 это необязательно. Но чтобы указать другому программисту, что вы либо реализовываете метод интерфейса, либо перезаписываете метод родителя, нужно написать эту аннотацию в строчке перед методом.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Я добавил эту строчку, однако пишет все ту же ошибку. Если бы я мог, я бы прислал скрин.

Comment: @headhunter225014 пришлите. https://imgur.com/upload?beta - там загрузите скрин, и скиньте ссылку на него

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uwCKzKG

Comment: @headhunter225014 да у вас тут две опечатки. В ответе неправильно написал - правильно mouseEntered, а не mouseEntred. Вторая опечатка - actionPerformed, а не actionPerfomed

Comment: Спасибо большое, наконец-то разобрался с этой ошибкой. Правда прога все равно не так работает, пойду дальше смотреть. Спасибо большое еще раз!